# cinder redirecting public endpoint to http

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I am running cinder client and trying to consume openstack endpoint but when i run cinder show the request are getting redirected to http endpoint and getting aborted

`#cinder --version
4.1.0`

`#cinder show 3988928-79b0-4e2e-90a9-38089af5b46e
ERROR: Unable to establish connection to http://mydomain:8776/v3/35f4380e80074591a9fd746c09e39d5c/volumes/detail?all_tenants=1&marker=6088358b-2905-42a1-aa50-a014c1dc8147: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`

any idea why this request getting redirected

Answer (score 0):

"cinder" CLI is been depreciated, instead use "openstack" CLI:

```
openstack volume show 3988928-79b0-4e2e-90a9-38089af5b46e"
```

If you still want to use "cinder show" for whatever reason, set OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION to 3.50.

```
export OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=3.50
cinder show 3988928-79b0-4e2e-90a9-38089af5b46e
```